# How do I determine the ideal value for my database.yml pool?

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, puma

Longtime listener, first-time caller here... my Postgres database says it allows the following:

Connections:
6/120

What should my corresponding "pool" setting be in this scenario? 6? 120? Something else entirely? Thanks in advance for any help here.

If it makes a difference I'm using Puma & Sidekiq to run a Rails 4 application on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

How many connections does your app use under typical load? Set the idle pool to that, and set the max pool to somewhere under the max allowed by the server.

But, that server connections setting should also be tuned to your application and hardware. It's typically some function of your core count, RAM and `work_mem` setting, and the kind of disks you have, but will also depend on what kind of queries your app typically runs.

(see here for some tips: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections)

Postgres is actually pretty forgiving: opening connections is cheap (an undersized pool), compared to many other databases; *idle* open connections (oversized pool) are also cheap (a few K of shared buffers, if memory serves).

It's really having more *active* connections than your resources allow that will cause problems, which is why the server-side configuration is more important.